# Breaking Loops as soon as their condition breaks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I would like to know how to break a loop as soon as its condition breaks.Its a little difficult to explain I will attach some code that will explain it well.I think I have to use things like break and continue but I am not sure where in my code should I place or maybe I need to do something else.your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
while 1:    
    if image1 appears on screen:
       # do some task(it includes multiple if statements in it too)
    else:
       #do task 1
       #do task 2
       #do task 3
```

I want as soon as image1 appears on screen else loop should exit even if it's incomplete.like if image1 appears when else loop is doing task 2 it should exit without completing it and move to the if loop.
with my current code if image1 appears on screen the else loop only exits when all 3 tasks are done.
**I want to exit the else loop not the if loop** and
**by exit or break I mean shift from else loop to if loop**

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `return`, like this:

```py
if image1 appears on screen:
   #do some task**
   return
else:
   press arrow key up for 2secs**
   press arrow down key for 2sec**
```

**UPD**
I suggest this code is a part of some function.
Otherwise you will have to put it inside some function since `return` can be called from inside a function only.
It is also a good practice to define and use functions.

Comment: `return` throws an error if used outside function. It does not work in loops.

Comment: You are right. I suggested this code is inside some function, not a flat code. I have updated the answer anyway.

Comment: If you use return it will stop the whole function. Then you would not be able to continue the function. If you use `break` it will stop the loop but the function will continue. BTW `return` is used not only to stop a function it is also used to return a value. Yeah, what you say is right , it is good practice to use functions

Answer (score 1):

If image1 appears on screen, the else part will not execute (that's how if-else functionality works).
You can just add "break" in the end of the if (before the else)

```
if image1 appears on screen:
       do some task**
       break
else:
       press arrow key up for 2secs**
       press arrow down key for 2sec**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `break` in `if` condition

```
#loop
    if image1 appears on screen:
        do some task**
        break # this will break the loop at running iteration
    else:
        press arrow key up for 2secs**
        press arrow down key for 2sec**
#loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` where you want to stop the loop -

```
if image1 appears on screen:
   #do some task**
   break
else:
   press arrow key up for 2secs**
   press arrow down key for 2sec**
```

You can also check [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

Comment: How your answer differs from my?

Comment: I used `break` instead of return

Comment: It was not me, I have no enough point for this :)

Comment: I know :). I was asking the person who downvoted for no reason. If they would say the reason, I would at least learn something new from any error.

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers. But i think I wasn't able to make my query clear.(I tried the break method I will update my code to explain better)